# jQuery show child divs when checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery

I have a select input which controls the display of different sets of checkboxes using jQuery. I.E. When you select different options it displays different divs containing more inputs.

```
<select type="select" name="set" id="set" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="set1">One</option>
    <option value="set2">Two</option>
</select>

<div id="set1" class="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" name="set1-questions1" id="set1-questions1">
  <div id="set1-questions1-qs"></div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="set2" class="checkboxes">
  ...
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#set').change(function(){
  $('.checkboxes').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

This works OK but I'd like the checkboxes within each div to control the display of the sub div. I.E you select an option from the select and then check a checkbox to display the sub div.

[DEMO with full markup and the first part working](http://jsfiddle.net/paulyabsley/GKJ8U/)

I don't know how to achieve the second part. Do I need a function to link the checkboxes to the corresponding divs and then show/hide based on if it is checked or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `change` handler to the checkboxes, and then toggle the corresponding `<div>` based on the state of the checkbox:

```
$('div.checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $('#' + this.id + '-qs').toggle( this.checked ); 
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKJ8U/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set some separate css on the child div's containing the content. Keep the logic to show the appropriate checkbox div, but add a change event for the checkboxes:

```
$(".checkboxes").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).next("div").show();
    }
});
```